# Câmera android personalizada

Tags: android, android-camera

Gostaria de fazer uma câmera Android personalizada em que fosse possível adicionar uma camada extra no momento da visualização e posteriormente fosse colocado na foto ao tirar a foto, porém, confesso que não sei bem como se faz essa câmera com layout personalizado e muito menos como deixar uma pré-visualização de uma "moldura" personalizada e salvar a foto que tirei com a mesma moldura, segue um exemplo que fiz no photoshop:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu sei que preciso ver algo com SurfaceView, porém só achei tutoriais antigos em que estão DEPRECATED na API, ta muito estranho... Porém, minha maior dúvida é a parte da moldura antes e depois de tirar a foto.

Answer (score 1):

Fala Vinithius,

Você precisa de uma câmera acoplada a um fragment, faz o seguinte:

1- Crie um Fragment, e no layout dele, adicione um FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/camera_container"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

2- No seu Fragment, crie uma chamada para a classe (fragment) da câmera, e adicione ele ao seu FrameLayout criado:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment targetFragment = null;
        targetFragment = NativeCameraFragment.newInstance(2);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.camera_container, targetFragment)
                .commit();
```

3- Agora crie a classe (fragment), NativeCameraFragment, e cole este código abaixo:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Take a picture directly from inside the app using this fragment.
 *
 * Reference: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html
 * Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
 * Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913181/camera-preview-is-not-restarting
 *
 * Created by Rex St. John (on behalf of AirPair.com) on 3/4/14.
 */
public class NativeCameraFragment extends BaseFragment {

    // Native camera.
    private Camera mCamera;

    // View to display the camera output.
    private CameraPreview mPreview;

    // Reference to the containing view.
    private View mCameraView;

    /**
     * Default empty constructor.
     */
    public NativeCameraFragment(){
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Static factory method
     * @param sectionNumber
     * @return
     */
    public static NativeCameraFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        NativeCameraFragment fragment = new NativeCameraFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * OnCreateView fragment override
     * @param inflater
     * @param container
     * @param savedInstanceState
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_native_camera, container, false);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        boolean opened = safeCameraOpenInView(view);

        if(opened == false){
            Log.d("CameraGuide","Error, Camera failed to open");
            return view;
        }

        // Trap the capture button.
        Button captureButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // get an image from the camera
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    }
                }
        );

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Recommended "safe" way to open the camera.
     * @param view
     * @return
     */
    private boolean safeCameraOpenInView(View view) {
        boolean qOpened = false;
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCameraView = view;
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);

        if(qOpened == true){
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity().getBaseContext(), mCamera,view);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
            mPreview.startCameraPreview();
        }
        return qOpened;
    }

    /**
     * Safe method for getting a camera instance.
     * @return
     */
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
    }

    /**
     * Clear any existing preview / camera.
     */
    private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {

        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        if(mPreview != null){
            mPreview.destroyDrawingCache();
            mPreview.mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Surface on which the camera projects it's capture results. This is derived both from Google's docs and the
     * excellent StackOverflow answer provided below.
     *
     * Reference / Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
     */
    class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        // SurfaceHolder
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;

        // Our Camera.
        private Camera mCamera;

        // Parent Context.
        private Context mContext;

        // Camera Sizing (For rotation, orientation changes)
        private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

        // List of supported preview sizes
        private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;

        // Flash modes supported by this camera
        private List<String> mSupportedFlashModes;

        // View holding this camera.
        private View mCameraView;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera, View cameraView) {
            super(context);

            // Capture the context
            mCameraView = cameraView;
            mContext = context;
            setCamera(camera);

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        /**
         * Begin the preview of the camera input.
         */
        public void startCameraPreview()
        {
            try{
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Extract supported preview and flash modes from the camera.
         * @param camera
         */
        private void setCamera(Camera camera)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            mCamera = camera;
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            mSupportedFlashModes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();

            // Set the camera to Auto Flash mode.
            if (mSupportedFlashModes != null && mSupportedFlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)){
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            }

            requestLayout();
        }

        /**
         * The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
         * @param holder
         */
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Dispose of the camera preview.
         * @param holder
         */
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (mCamera != null){
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        }

        /**
         * React to surface changed events
         * @param holder
         * @param format
         * @param w
         * @param h
         */
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

                // Set the auto-focus mode to "continuous"
                parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

                // Preview size must exist.
                if(mPreviewSize != null) {
                    Camera.Size previewSize = mPreviewSize;
                    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
                }

                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Calculate the measurements of the layout
         * @param widthMeasureSpec
         * @param heightMeasureSpec
         */
        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
            final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

            if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null){
                mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Update the layout based on rotation and orientation changes.
         * @param changed
         * @param left
         * @param top
         * @param right
         * @param bottom
         */
        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            if (changed) {
                final int width = right - left;
                final int height = bottom - top;

                int previewWidth = width;
                int previewHeight = height;

                if (mPreviewSize != null){
                    Display display = ((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

                    switch (display.getRotation())
                    {
                        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
                            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                            break;
                        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
                            break;
                        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.height;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.width;
                            break;
                        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
                            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(180);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                mCameraView.layout(0, height - scaledChildHeight, width, height);
            }
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param sizes
         * @param width
         * @param height
         * @return
         */
        private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int width, int height)
        {
            // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942378/android-camera-will-not-work-startpreview-fails
            Camera.Size optimalSize = null;

            final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
            double targetRatio = (double) height / width;

            // Try to find a size match which suits the whole screen minus the menu on the left.
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes){

                if (size.height != width) continue;
                double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
                if (ratio <= targetRatio + ASPECT_TOLERANCE && ratio >= targetRatio - ASPECT_TOLERANCE){
                    optimalSize = size;
                }
            }

            // If we cannot find the one that matches the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement.
            if (optimalSize == null) {
                // TODO : Backup in case we don't get a size.
            }

            return optimalSize;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Picture Callback for handling a picture capture and saving it out to a file.
     */
    private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image retrieval failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                // Restart the camera preview.
                safeCameraOpenInView(mCameraView);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Used to return the camera File output.
     * @return
     */
    private File getOutputMediaFile(){

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "UltimateCameraGuideApp");

        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("Camera Guide", "Required media storage does not exist");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");

        DialogHelper.showDialog( "Success!","Your picture has been saved!",getActivity());

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

No layout do **NativeCameraFragment.java**, que está declarado como **R.layout.fragment_native_camera**, você deve colocar o espaço onde ficará a câmera, que é o:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

E agora você pode estilizar da forma que quiser, colocando molduras e fotos a vontade.

Qualquer dúvida posta aqui que te ajudo a montar certinho.

Abraços.

Comment: Consegui fazer com que a câmera funcione, mas como adiciona essa camada de moldura no preview e na foto final?

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma boa maneira de colocar a moldura no Preview e na foto final, segue partes do código:

Moldura no Preview:

```
    surfaceView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.moldura_default);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
```

Moldura na foto final (Pois a moldura do preview não vai para a foto):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...
    //Código...
    //...

    jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
            file_image = getDirc();
            if(!file_image.exists() && !file_image.mkdirs()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Não pode criar diretorio para salvar imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
            String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
            String photofile =  dir.trim().replace(" ", "").toLowerCase() + "_" +
                    date.trim().replace(" ", "") + ".jpeg";
            file_name = file_image.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + photofile;
            File picFile = new File(file_name);

            try{
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
                outputStream.write(bytes);
                outputStream.close();

            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            }catch (IOException ex){

            }finally {

            }
            refreshCamera();
            refreshGallery(picFile);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_name);
            Bitmap mutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Bitmap bittoMerge = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.moldura_default);
            Bitmap aux = getResizedBitmap(bittoMerge, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            mergeImages(mutableBitmap, aux, 0, 0, null, file_name);

        }
    };

    //...
    //Código...
    //...

    }

    //...
    //Código...
    //...

    //Redimensionar Bitmap de moldura de acordo com a foto tirada
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        bm.recycle();
        return resizedBitmap;
    }

    //...
    //Código...
    //...

    //Metodo que faz a união da "moldura" com a foto e gera um arquivo de imagem finalizado
    public void mergeImages(Bitmap originalBitmap, Bitmap bitmapToMerge, float left, float top, Paint paint, String path) {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(originalBitmap);

    canvas.scale((float) 1.0, (float) 1.0);

    canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, new Matrix(), null);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToMerge, left, top, paint);

    canvas.save();

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(path);
        originalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
        // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

    //...
    //Código...
    //...

//Cria diretorio da foto original
private File getDirc(){
    File dics = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "/teste/");
    return new File(dics,dir.trim().replace(" ", ""));
}

    //...
    //Código...
    //...

    public void refreshCamera(){
    if(surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null){
        //Preview surface não existe
        return;
    }
    //Para preview antes de fazer as mudanças
    try{
        camera.stopPreview();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    //Coloca no preview tamanho e faz alguma mudança de tamanho, rotação ou reformata as mudanças aqui,
    // inicia o preview com novas configurações.
    try{
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}

public void refreshGallery(File file){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

    //...
    //Código...
    //...
```

Comigo funciona bem até o momento, espero que isso ajude...